# A Bookmarklet with Socket.IO

Tags: socket.io, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a sample bookmarklet code that:

- Inject jQuery
- Setup Socket.IO and start listening for messages

The idea is to send websocket messages to the page, that will be transformed into keypress events.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I build my own bookmarklet based on this code:
https://gist.github.com/2897748

I include jQuery and Socket.IO and everything is fine

Comment: A sample/example that does not include Socket.IO is simply not sufficient.

Comment: It's 1 line in the boilerplate, // doStuff() all the tricky part is the boilerplate.